# Time Line of Cash Flows Visualization

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have an excel sheet with 6 columns:

- 3 different cash flows (30%,60% and 10% of the project value)
- 3 columns with their respective dates

As an example, suppose total contract value is 100 USD, I receive USD 30 on 15.02.2019, USD 60 on 15.03.2020 and USD 10 on 15.03.2021. This is one row and 6 columns.

I want to present this information in 1 single chart/visualization. There are abot 200 rows and the dates are not in a particular order, it's random.
When I try to combine the  data X axis (dates) and all the 3 Cash flows (on Y axis), it doesn't make sense, it gets chaotic and moreover the dates only come up for the 30% Cash flow.

I want X axis with all the dates and on Y axis to have the cash flows with 3 legends (30%,60% and 10%) on their respective dates. I am not an advanced user in Excel so would appreciate your help!
What to do?

Comment: Does Addoodi’s approach answer your question?  If yes, please say so.  Otherwise, please [edit] your question to more clearly describe the data you have and the chart you want.  For example, is it theoretically possible that your data set might contain 600 different dates?  For the chart, ideally, draw something with a drawing tool and upload that. (We prefer that you upload images to imgur through Super User.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are trying to do is make a "Combo Chart".
I've made an example below to help:

```
    A           B       C           D       E           F
1   Date        Cash    Date        Cash    Date        Cash
2   1/1/2019    20      1/2/2019    10      1/1/2019    80
3   1/2/2019    10      1/4/2019    10      1/3/2019    70
4   1/3/2019    50      1/6/2019    20      1/5/2019    50
5   1/4/2019    70      1/8/2019    20      1/7/2019    30
6   1/5/2019    80              
7   1/6/2019    30              
8   1/7/2019    10              
9   1/8/2019    20
```

A good starting point is to select all of the cells A1:F9 and insert any chart.
Select the created chart and under the "Chart tools" you will find "Design". In there, there is a button saying "Change Chart Type". You will want to click on that and change the chart type to "Combo" (The last option). Don't bother much on the other details now and click "ok". The chart will change into a new type of mess (don't worry).
Now on the "Design" menu click on "Select Data". Remove all the Date columns from the "Legend entries" (left box) and only keep the cash. Now on each of the cash column, assign its corresponding dates from the "Horizontal" (Right box) by clicking edit and highlighting the date associated with this column. Click OK and voilà.
If you want you can go back to change chart type and modify the type of each column chart type (lines or bars or whatever).
Hope this helps

Comment: I tried applying the steps to your example data set.But its still confusing-attached link with picture. Link (https://imgur.com/a/Fw5UNmc). The dates corresponding to Cash1 and Cash 3 column are wrong. Even though I select Date 1 associated with Cash 1 -it automatically associates it with Date 2.Similarly Cash 3 gets associated with Date 2. I think its simple but don't know why Im  not able to do this.

Comment: Great. Just like you are showing now, you can move the purple box (highlighting the dates) to the correct ones. Confirm the same with all lines.